# replace non-ASCII characters to UTF-8 format

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode, unicode-string

I would like to know if there is any way to find a character (uft-8 format) equivalent to a non-ASCII character.

I've done several tests with the unidecode library, but it doesn't completely satisfy what I need.

For example, consider this characters:

```
import unidecode

x = 'ⁱ, ᴠ, Ғ, Ƭ, ѳ, ❶'
unidecode.unidecode(x)

Output = "i, V, G', T, f, "
```

I would like something like: "i, v, f, t, o, 1"

There must be a way?
Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: "I would like something like: "i, v, f, t, o, 1"" Okay; and *why* is `"i, V, G', T, f, "` not good enough? What is the actual rule you want to apply? If you expect that every character should have a specific mapping, with no particular pattern to it, then you will need to just have some kind of hard-coded mapping (whether you make it yourself or use a library like `unidecode`) - there is no getting around that. It's only possible to write an algorithm for things that have an algorithmic approach.

Comment: Also: did you try *reading the documentation* for `unidecode`, to see if there are any configuration options that could get you results more like what you want?

Comment: `Ғ` is not related to `F` at all. It's mainly used to represent voice velar and uvular fricatives (think French "r") in Turkic languages that use the Cyrillic language. Just because two glyphs look similar does not mean there's a mapping that represents the similarity.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, there's not necessarily a relation because characters simply look alike. Seems most similar examples online are mainly focused on removing accents and would use the standard Python library `unicodedata`. It uses standard approaches to converting to ASCII like NFKD (NFKD explained [here](https://dencode.com/string/unicode-normalization))

### More Common unicodedata Approach

```
import unicodedata
str_unicode = u"ⁱ, ᴠ, Ғ, Ƭ, ѳ, ❶"

#replace = any characters that can't be translated will be replaced with ?
print(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',str_unicode).encode("ascii",'replace'))
#will ignore any errors
print(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',str_unicode).encode("ascii",'ignore'))
```

### unicodedata Output

```
'i, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?'
'i, , , , , '
```

### unidecode Map with Translate

The `unidecode` library seems closer for your specific example. I think you will have to augment it though with a `translate` call to cleanup characters the library doesn't map.

I added a second example a character that couldn't be mapped. I added paragraph mark "¶" mapped to "P" for reference

```
import unicodedata
import unidecode

#Script
str_unicode = u"ⁱ, ᴠ, Ғ, Ƭ, ѳ, ❶, ¶"
dict_mapping = str.maketrans("❶¶","1P")

str_unidecode = unidecode.unidecode(str_unicode)
str_unidecode_translated = unidecode.unidecode(str_unicode.translate(dict_mapping))

print(str_unidecode)
print(str_unidecode_translated)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stephan, your answer helped me a lot and I already have a direction.